# Reference Request: Elementary embeddings between $L(V_{\alpha})$'s

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

By  $L(V_{\alpha})$, I mean the least inner model containing $V_{\alpha}$.

I'm especially interested in e.e's  $j:L(V_{\alpha}) \to  L(V_{\beta})$, where $ \omega < \vert \beta \vert < \vert \alpha \vert $.

I know Laver did some work where $ \alpha = \beta = \lambda + 2 $ for a singular cardinal $\lambda$ with countable cofinality.

Comment: I'm assuming you assume choice in the outset universe. In that case, at least for $\lambda$ being a limit cardinal, it has to have countable cofinality. Otherwise by a theorem of Shelah, it cannot have an elementary embedding like that.

Comment: I figured something like that is why Laver madr that assumption. Do you have a source of the Shelah result?